# ASP.NET GridView with 'Save All' feature

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

**Scenario :** I wanted to provide a GridView where the user can enter data row by row and display it(I did not bind to a database yet). I gave a footer where the user enters data and clicks add to add the data to the GridView.  Finally, I gave a '*Save All*' button to save the whole GridView data to the database.

**What I did :** I implemented it in this way where the data gets saved to an XML file when each row is added to the GridView. When the user clicks '*Save All*' all the data in the file gets saved in the database. This implementation works perfectly.

**My Question :** My problem was that I found this implementation a bit complex and so i want to know if there are any other ways to do this(Javascript/jquery or any other). Any ideas/suggestions/links/sample codes are welcome.

Comment: Why you need this intermediate state to save data to XML file and then save all option? you can save the data to the database on you'r footer add button click? http://itzonesl.blogspot.com/2012/11/insert-update-delete-example-in-aspnet.html

Comment: No my requirement is in that way :-)

Comment: If it's already working then it's Ok. Would you mind starting from scratch again? You could save the data as JSON, Javascript object and have them persisted in the database later. But you'll need to look that up. Good luck.

Comment: what you have done for writing to `XML`. How do you handle `multiple users` wring the same file (XML). Have you use any kind of `lock` etc.

Comment: @codingbiz :thanks for the idea. are there any links or can you provide me with sample code? because i am new to javascript.

Comment: if you are willing to start from scratch, jqGrid might be a good option for you. You would be able to add a new row to the grid, you would be able to edit each cell by clicking any where in the row you want to edit. Its not very simple, but a very responsive control. Have a look at the below link, it shows what you want. I can even provide you startup code if you want.
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your response guys. I used the [Obout grid(Excel style)](http://www.obout.com/grid/commands/aspnet_commands_excel_style_full.aspx) to achieve it. It works just as I wanted.